# Can not delete the file after upload it to FTP by FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp

Here is my code to upload a file :

```
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));

                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("****", "*****");
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = true;

                reqFTP.ContentLength = stream.Length;
                // reqFTP.EnableSsl = true; // it's FTPES type of ftp

                int buffLen = 2048;
                byte[] buff = new byte[buffLen];
                int contentLen;

                try
                {
                    Stream ftpStream = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();
                    contentLen = stream.Read(buff, 0, buffLen);
                    while (contentLen != 0)
                    {
                        ftpStream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                        contentLen = stream.Read(buff, 0, buffLen);
                    }

                    ftpStream.Flush();
                    ftpStream.Close();
                    ftpStream.Dispose();

                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {

                    return false;
                }
                //delete image from local

                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();

                DeleteFile();
```

`DeleteFile` method try to delete the uploaded file; but it has an error that the file is being used by my app and so it can not delete it. Is there any one to help me about this issue?!

**UPDATE1** :

```
private void DeleteFile()
    {
        DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"Direectory Contains uploaded file");
        foreach (FileInfo file in DirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of `DeleteFile`?

Comment: I will update my Question

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to delete the local file? The error says the file is still in use. Wrap the code where you initalize the stream variable in a using block.